# libinput - Tap to click only for three fingers

Tags: libinput

I want to use a three finger touchpad tap as middle click, but I want to have one and two finger taps disabled in favour of left and right click.

It seems that libinput only allows enabling or disabling tapping, is there anyway to configure tapping per tap type?